# How do I convert a DjVu document to PDF in Linux using only command line tools?

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion, djvu

I've got some documents in DjVu which I'll like convert to PDF. Is there a way to do this using command line OSS tools?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[djvu2pdf](https://0x2a.at/site/projects/djvu2pdf/) should fit the bill, it's a small script that makes use of the djvulibre toolset. If not, there are [other methods](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232038) that require multiple command-line tools.

Comment: What's a pity that, currently there is not djvu2pdf tool in [Arch repo](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=djvu2pdf) and old ver in [Arch User repo](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?O=0&K=djvu2pdf&do_Search=Go)

Comment: Installing `djvulibre-bin` using apt-get and then installing the deb file in that link did the trick.

Comment: On mac you `djvu2pdf` is available via [`MacPorts`](http://www.macports.org).

Comment: Mac users can also run `brew install djvu2pdf` to install the program and `djvu2pdf file.djvu` to convert. Homebrew takes care of downloading all its dependencies

Comment: `djvu2pdf` works although it produces a slightly bigger file than `ddjvu` with compression enabled. Other issue is that it doesn't copy the table of contents of the source document.

Comment: `djvu2pdf` works but does not preserve the text layer. It is essentially a wrapper for `ddjvu` and thus running `ddjvu -format=pdf` will produce the same output. For an approach that preserves the text layer see [here](https://superuser.com/a/1806567).

Answer (score 49):

The `ddjvu` program
(which is part of the standard `djvulibre` package) will do this:

```
$ ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=85 -verbose a.djvu a.pdf
```

---

Warning: this produces large files
(but PDF files made by Christoph Sieghart's script are of the same size).

---

I also wrote the following small shell script some years ago. 
It does the same automatically. (Save this as `djvu2pdf.sh`.)

```
#!/bin/sh

# convert DjVu -> PDF
# usage:  djvu2pdf.sh  <file.djvu>

i="$1"
echo "------------ converting $i to PDF ----------------";
o="$(basename "$i" .djvu).pdf"
echo "[ writing output to $o ] "

ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=85 -verbose "$i" "$o"
```

---

The `djvu2pdf` script by Christoph Sieghart does essentially the same.

Comment: Is there a way to make OCR layer of the DjVu come through into the PDF?

Comment: using `ddjvu` turned my 6.3 mb djvu file into a 1.7 gig pdf file.

Comment: something is wrong. this should not happen. you can post here the link to the file.

Answer (score 25):

```
$ djvups input.djvu | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

In my case the output file was **10x smaller** than with ddjvu. Both `djvups` and `ps2pdf` present in ubuntu repository.

```
$ sudo apt-get install djvulibre-bin ghostscript
```

I've found this method in `man ddjvu`, so always read manuals ;)

> An alternate way to produce  PDF  file  consists in first using
>   djvups(1) and convert the resulting PostScript file to PDF. Which
>   method gives better results depends on the contents of the DJVU file
>   and on  the  capabilities of the PS to PDF converter.

Comment: +1 for preserving any text layer in the djvu file

Comment: +1 for that apt command XD

Comment: This is the only one preserving the text layer. But increases filesize 10-fold for me.

Comment: Did not preserve the text layer for me, instead produced garbled characters and indeed increased the file size by a factor of ten.

Comment: My file went from 5,5MB to 65MB, didn't preserve text and some pages were upside down.

Answer (score 23):

What about simply using DJView and export as PDF?

1. Goto Synaptic Package Manager (System - Administration - Synaptic Package Manager)
2. Install DJview4
3. Run DJview (Applications - Graphics - DJView4)
4. Open your .djvu document
5. Menu - Export As: PDF

Look at http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232038

Comment: The question was about using command line only, so this can be automated.

Comment: I tested with a book of 1.4Mb. The output was 8Mb (much larger but still decent). However, the text is not searchable anymore

Answer (score 12):

If you don't care about colors and images you can get much smaller files if you drop the colors and use instead:

> `ddjvu -format=pdf -mode=black` input.djvu output.pdf

Texts, codes and formulas looks perfectly, but most of the images are gone

Answer (score 3):

I've changed the @Maxim script a little ...

```
#!/bin/bash
# convert DjVu -> PDF
# usage:  djvu2pdf.sh [-q quality | -b] <infile.djvu> [outfile.pdf]

mode='color'
quality=80

aparse() {
  while [ $# != 0 ] ; do
    case "$1" in
    -q|--quality)
      quality=${2}
      shift
      ;;
    -b|--black)
      mode='black'
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
}
aparse "$@"

i="$1"
o=${2:-$(basename $i .djvu).pdf}
if [ -f  "$o" ]; then 
  echo "file $o exists, override [Y/n]?"
  read ans
  case "$ans" in 
   n|N) exit 1;;
  esac
fi
echo "[ converting $i to $o ] "

cmd="ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=$quality -mode=$mode -verbose $i $o "

echo "[ executing $cmd ] "
$cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS users you can install djvu2pdf like this:

```
$brew install djvu2pdf
```

How to use it(works for any Xnix like system):

```
$djvu2pdf nameBook.djvu nameBookToCreate.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

For an approach that preserves the text layer<sup>1</sup> one can use [`djvu2pdf`](https://github.com/vindvaki/djvu2pdf) described in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/964527). The general approach is described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1114330) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/122604).

For macOS a minor tweak is required.

BSD `readlink -f` behaviour differs from GNU readlink. This can be fixed by installing [GNU coreutuils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) and changing `readlink -f` to `greadlink -f`.

---

<sub>1. According to the description the table of contents will also be preserved, but I haven't tested that.</sub>