# Can you recommend me a program to organize my ebook collection?

Tags: pdf, ebook, djvu

I have many pdf and djvu books on my PC (ebooks, datasheets, manuals, scans etc).
Can you recommend me a software to organize my collection of books (like there is a software to organize music collection).
Both Linux and Windows software is appeciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a piece of software called http://calibre-ebook.com/ , unfortunately it won't fit your djvu requirement, on the up-side it does support a lot of eBook formats.

There is a question here, detailing converting djvu to a more common format:

[How to convert djvu file to pdf or other more common file format?](https://superuser.com/questions/185523/how-to-convert-djvu-file-to-pdf-or-other-more-common-file-format)

Comment: confound it, i was about to suggest the same thing ;)

Comment: Oh, a great piece of software, thanks! But I think a djvu format is pretty good for scans, it is a pity that it is unsupported!

Comment: djvu should be supported by now

Comment: You might want take a look at [BookFusion](http://bookfusion.com/reading) they also have a Calibre plugin