# Can I create comments inside djvu files?

Tags: djvu, comments

I sometimes use `pdfxchange` for windows when I want to study pdf files, as I am able to comment, draw stuff, highlight, etc.

Is there any software that could do that (for either Windows or Linux) for `djvu` files in a simple, straightforward way (as how `pdfxchange` handles PDF files)?

Comment: Also for iOS if anyone has suggestions would be great.

Comment: If there is still interest, please post on the Software Recommendations SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Linux**: According to [this forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/djvu/discussion/103285/thread/ad176492/) from a year ago, there are two options in Linux: [djvusmooth](http://jwilk.net/software/djvusmooth) and the [GNU ELPA djvu package](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/djvu.html).

**Windows**: [WinDjView](http://windjview.sourceforge.net/) has user annotations.

**Mac**: I don't know of any.

And of course, if you only have a few DjVu files, there is always the option of [converting to PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/185523/how-to-convert-djvu-file-to-pdf-or-other-more-common-file-format) and then using your favorite PDF viewer.

Comment: Are you sure that zathura can do that? I've been using it for a while now and I can't see how it does..

Comment: No, I was basing that off what I read on the zathura website, but now that I revisit it I think I made a mistake. I've edited my answer. (If you find d that it's possible, feel free to edit back.)

Comment: WindjView supports bookmarks, not annotations. The difference is that the bookmarks don't appear visible on the page, they are texts associated with a page, but the program doesn't inform you automatically when there are notes for that page, making it really acward if one wants to take notes on a specific part of the page.

Comment: Santropedro, the [website](http://windjview.sourceforge.net/) says it supports "User-created bookmarks and annotations".  You're saying that's wrong?

Comment: @JessRiedel Sorry for delay, you didn't notify me with "@" to respond. YES, surprisingly, they are mistaken. I installed the program and they don't have annotations at all. I'm seeing it in front of my eyes. They DO have bookmarks, though.

Comment: @Santropedro You can do it with WinDjView. Just select some piece of text, right-click and "highlight text..." introduce then your comment and click "ok". Unfortunately MacDjView does not support this option at the present version.