# What is the djvu2pdf.rb in Homebrew?

Tags: pdf, homebrew, djvu

I recently downloaded a textbook as a .djvu file (*sighs*, not a PDF. wth is this). I found a way to view it and a way to convert it on the Internet (cool).

Recently however, I downloaded Homebrew for my Mac, and I found a strange file that was called [djvu2pdf.rb](https://gist.github.com/doctordoder/8551781) (this sounds like it does what I want it to do) inside of the folder ~/homebrew/Library/Formula.

Among the spotlight search for djvu I did were these files:
[image: spotlight search]

What is this file for? Does it have anything to do with converting a .djvu to a .pdf? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a formula for a program that Homebrew can install for you (with `brew install djvu2pdf`). To find out more about the program, type `brew home djvu2pdf` to open up its home page in your default browser (that's true of all Homebrew formulas).

Comment: In Homebrew's terminology, a "formula" is a set of instructions written in the Ruby programming language to install a software with Homebrew (which is also written in Ruby.)  It is not the software you want to install itself.

Comment: Now that I've installed it, since there is no help from the manpages or online about [what the app does](http://0x2a.at/s/projects/djvu2pdf), where do I find this application on my computer? I can't run it from the command line because I don't know how it operates.

Comment: You might want to read up on how Homebrew works, e.g. read https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki. Basically Homebrew provides a bunch of formulas, which (as nodakai said) are Ruby scripts that install software from various places. The actual files belonging to each package are located in `/usr/local/Cellar/<formula_name>/<version>` -- or in your case, `~/homebrew/Cellar/<formula_name>/<version>`. If Homebrew's installed in the default place, they then get symlinked into `/usr/local/{lib,share,bin,etc.}`; but since you have it in `~/homebrew` I'm not sure where the links go.