# How to convert DJVU to character recognizable PDF FIle?

Tags: pdf, conversion, pdf-reader, djvu

I have a a DJVU file where I can select, copy, highlight the text of it, i.e. the DJVU is text readable or character recognizable. I want to convert this file to character recognizable pdf file. Is there online charge-free system or free software to that?

Thanks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/185523/777184

Comment: @Madhubala Could u specifically tell which one converts to text recognizable pdf file plz?

Comment: Added it as an answer , check if it helps and feel free to accept if it answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use DjVuLibre : [DjVu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/djvu/)

> In DjVuLibre
>
> To convert it to pdf : File > Export as… > PDF format

To convert pdf file to character recognizable pdf file :

> you can use Acrobat Pro/Standard DC 2020 ([direct link Acrobat
> Pro/Standard DC 2020](https://prodesigntools.com/acrobat-dc-2020-direct-download-links.html)(it comes with trial version)
>
> in Acrobat >  Tools > Scan and OCR > Recognize Text > in this file

[image: IMG1]
[image]

Or

> you can use tesseract-ocr : [tesseract-ocr download page](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html).I use it
> with [wsl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)/linux.Here is the bash script (it uses ghostscript &&
> tesseract)

```
#!/bin/bash

notify-send "started gs" && pdftoppm -r 660 *.pdf outputname -png && for i in *png; do b=`basename "$i" .png`; tesseract "$i" "$b" pdf; done && gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile=finished.pdf outputname-*.pdf && notify-send "done" && notify-send "deleting left overs" && rm *png && rm outputname-*.pdf && notify-send "cleaned"
```