# Searching for text in DJVU files through the Windows search panel

Tags: windows, search, ocr, djvu

I have many DJVU files with OCR in one folder. What should be done or how can I search for words in these files through the search field in the folder (top left)? There is a reference to the DjVuOCR plugin for Windows by Vladimir Levenshtein on the internet, but I cannot find it anywhere. Converting 798 DJVU files to PDF with working OCR is not feasible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do the files have searchable text within?  If not, Windows Search and most 3rd party search Apps won't help much

Comment: Yes, the files have OCR and the text in them is searchable, but so far only through the WinDjView application, for example. But I don't want to open every file and search. I need to search through all the files at once.

Comment: This seems very niche and that your best solution is e.g. live Linux USB + https://github.com/jwilk-archive/ocrodjvu + bash script for batch processing.

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/185523/how-to-convert-djvu-file-to-pdf-or-other-more-common-file-format) help ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file extension and make sure in Indexing Properties, that Windows Search properties includes Content (it may not by default).

Then if you change you may need to rebuild your Index.

However, once done, if Windows finds the content, it will list all the files with that word.

I have done this for other Indexed Content and it works fine.

Control Panel, Indexing Options, Advanced, File Types and check your Extension for the Content Setting.

Windows Search works best if these files are in one main folder, so that you do not have to search your entire drive.

Windows Search has evolved and is very good in Windows 10 and really good in Windows 11.

Upon following all the suggestions here, you find that Windows Search cannot find content in the OCR files, then you may need a 3rd party search tool

Please see:

[Windows Search Apps](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-best-free-search-tools-windows-10/)

In this list, I have here and use occasionally Ultra Search (From Jam Software, the makers of Tree Size).  Search My Files (Nirsoft) may be useful as well (I use Nirsoft Utilities but not that one).

==============

Finally, if none of the suggestions for the file type you have do not work, you will very most likely have to identify the files manually.

Comment: This won't work because WIndows indexing doesn't implement OCR.

Comment: Author says the OCR they have have are searchable. So it should indeed work if Content has been selected.   OP: You may wish to edit your question to say the OCR are searchable.

Comment: They said they looked for OCR plugin but only found one that's not downloadable anywhere.

Comment: If the files are half-decent OCR then Windows Content setting should handle them.

Comment: After setting up according to John's instructions, the indexing process took about 30 minutes. Unfortunately, the situation is the same after it, Windows cannot search in DJVU files with OCR. It probably really requires installing some software to help Windows view DJVU files.

Comment: I added a list of 3rd party search tools, one of which I use.

Comment: I've tried the apps below and unfortunately none of them can search for text in DJVU files.
UltraSearch, Agent Ransack, Glarysoft Quick Search, AstroGrep, Everything

Comment: If none of the search tools work, you will have to look at each file

Comment: @Jose because none of them can handle OCR. This answer doesn't consider OCR at all, for some reason it tries to target regular text files.