# dvju to pdf including text layer

Tags: pdf, djvu

Trying to convert djvu with text layer to pdf with text layer. I've tried all the methods in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/100572/how-do-i-convert-a-djvu-document-to-pdf-in-linux-using-only-command-line-tools) and none of them preserve the text layer.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you have two options:

1. Use [ocrodjvu](http://jwilk.net/software/ocrodjvu) and [pdfbeads](http://rubygems.org/gems/pdfbeads) as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46233/converting-djvu-to-pdf/122604#122604).

   The relevant commands assuming that your DJVU file is called `sample.djvu` and you want to convert page 10 to PDF including the text layer:

   `djvu2hocr -p 10 sample.djvu | sed 's/ocrx/ocr/g' > pg10.html`

   `ddjvu -format=tiff -page=10 sample.djvu pg10.tif`

   `pdfbeads -o pg10.pdf`
2. Use [Djview4](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/djview4.html) to convert the DJVU file to PDF and then use [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) to perform OCR. It takes time but it is damn good (even on two-column documents).

In principle the two options should work on Mac, Windows and Linux. For option 2. you will need [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on Mac and Linux.

I tried option 1. with a single page and it did not finish in less than 10 minutes on a recent laptop with a quad-core processor and 8 GB of RAM. YMMV.

Option 2. took two hours on a 50 page document on a recent desktop computer with a quad-core processor and 16 GB of RAM, but the results are impressive.